# Images in reopen review (side-by-side view) are larger than column width

Tags: bug, review, images, rendering, page-rendering

I was reviewing [this item from Ask Ubuntu's reopen queue](https://askubuntu.com/review/reopen/622597) and noticed that the `side-by-side` view is rendered incorrectly.

The images are too large, the one in the left column overlaps with the right column and the one in the right column extends into the sidebar.

[image]

This behaviour has been confirmed in Firefox and Chromium browsers by me and various other users.

It's probably caused by these not matching styles:

```
#revisions .sidebyside-diff > div {
    width: 330px !important;
}

#revisions .sidebyside-diff > div img {
    max-width: 410px;
}
```